# Insert results of a stored procedure into a temp table in SQL 2012 (The metadata could not be determined because every code)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am stuck to insert reults from stored proc to temp table in `SQL 2012`, My old code is working perfectly on `SQL 2008` but `2012` got that error.

> Msg 11529, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set,
>   Line 1 The metadata could not be determined because every code path
>   results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.
>
> Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set,
>   Line 1 Cannot find the object "#Tethys_ReportGenerator_Tbl" because it
>   does not exist or you do not have permissions.

My stored proc emit reults set which has dynamic columns, sometimes it has 10 and sometimes it has more 15 .Please help me out above issue.

My old code are given below also some code tried of 2012 is given below:

```
select a.* into [tempdb].[dbo].[tempBase]
from openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=.;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=SSPI', 'SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF ; exec LIQ_TradeBustTrader5895.dbo.price_report @loginID = ''ALL'', @tableName = ''order_msgs'', @firmname = ''ALL'', @AssetClass = ''All'', @OutputBustRecords=0, @ManualOrder=0, @TimeFrom=''0:0'', @TimeTo=''23:59'', @ExcludeSimulatedTrades=0, @SingleTable =1 ') AS a;
```

For 2012

```
select a.* into [tempdb].[dbo].[tempBase]                           
from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (N'EXEC LIQ_TradeBustTrader5895.dbo.price_report @loginID = ''ALL'', @tableName = ''order_msgs'', @firmname = ''ALL'', @AssetClass = ''All'', @OutputBustRecords=0, @ManualOrder=0, @TimeFrom=''0:0'', @TimeTo=''23:59'', @ExcludeSimulatedTrades=0, @SingleTable =1', null, 2) AS a;
```

Comment: Have you tried to use Linked server? Actual code of your SP would be helpful. It looks like second error is irrelevant to code you've provided. It can be somewhere else or deep down inside of `LIQ_TradeBustTethysTrader5895.dbo.Tethys_price_report`

Comment: See that link `http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12739/whats-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-temp-table-in-sql-server-that-can-hold-the-re` My proc return temp table that I want to use into temp table.

Comment: The syntax is correct, can you execute the SP outside of the `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` function?